# The commutator of the product of 2 groups

Tags: group-theory, direct-product, derived-subgroup

Let $G=H\times A$ be the internal product of $A$ and $H$,

I proved that if "$A$ is abelian then $G′=H′$ "

But if we were not given that $A$ is abelian is $G′=H′\times A′$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a typical generator of $G'$, by picking any two elements of $G$, namely $g_1 = (h_1,a_1)$ and $g_2 = (h_2,a_2)$, and forming their commutator:
\begin{align*}
[g_1,g_2] &= g_1 \cdot g_2 \cdot g_1^{-1} \cdot g_2^{-1} \\
&= (h_1,a_1) \cdot (h_2, a_2) \cdot (h_1^{-1},a_1^{-1}) \cdot (h_2^{-1},a_2^{-1}) \\
&= (h_1 \cdot h_2 \cdot h_1^{-1} \cdot h_2^{-1}, a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_1^{-1} \cdot a_2^{-1} )\\
&= ([h_1,h_2],[a_1,a_2]) \\
&\in H' \times A'
\end{align*}
Since elements of the form $[g_1,g_2]$ are generators of $G'$, this proves that $G' < H' \times A'$. The opposite inclusion should be obvious. So yes, $G' = H' \times A'$.

Comment: but the elements of $g$ are not of the type ordered pair. If $g\in G$ then $g=ha$ for unique $h\in H$ and $a\in A$. also $ha=ah$ for all elements $h\in H$ and $a\in A$.

Comment: Internal and external direct product are almost the same, in practice it's just a matter of notation changes. Here's a quick [wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Algebraic_structure), for example, but you can also look this up in any group theory book. Briefly, for an external direct product the group rule is what I wrote, using ordered pairs, for example $(h_1,a_1) \cdot (h_2,a_2)=(h_1h_2,a_1a_2)$. For an internal direct product the group rule is $(h_1 \cdot a_1) \cdot (h_2 \cdot  a_2) = (h_1 \cdot h_2) \cdot (a_1 \cdot a_2)$.

Comment: Regarding the commutativity relation $ha=ah$, you can see that relation in use in going from the second line to the third line of my displayed equations, where six consecutive occurrences of that commutativity relation are applied. If you like, you can write that line without ordered pair notation like this: $$(h_1a_1)(h_2a_2)(h_1^{-1}a_1^{-1})(h_2^{-1}a_2^{-1}) = h_1h_2h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}a_1a_2a_1^{-1}a_2^{-1}$$